# SQL: Capturing first row in WHILE loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop

I'm thinking my issue is based on how I've written the loop, but how it is written is how I've come to understand loops. So I'm really wondering if there is a way to consolidate this? As it sits, I have 2 sections: the first which captures the very first row, and it exists solely because my second section will capture the 2nd row up through the max row (as determined by `@I`).

Is there a way to get the first row inside the loop?

```
DECLARE @COUNTER TINYINT = 15

DECLARE @EndDate DATE= CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(GETDATE()), '-', MONTH(GETDATE()), '-01') AS DATE)
DECLARE @StartDate DATE= DATEADD(MONTH, -12, @EndDate)


--THIS SECTION EXISTS SO I CAN CAPTURE THE FIRST ROW

       SELECT count = COUNT(DISTINCT value)
       FROM [TABLE]
       WHERE DATE >= @StartDate
             AND DATE < @EndDate


--THE LOOP BELOW CAPTURES THE SECOND ROW THROUGH THE REST OF THE ROWS BASED ON THE UPPER THRESHOLD OF @I

DECLARE @I TINYINT
SET @I = 0
WHILE @I <= @COUNTER
    BEGIN

        SET @I = @I + 1
               SELECT count = COUNT(DISTINCT value)
               FROM [TABLE]
               WHERE DATE >= DATEADD(MONTH, -(@I), @StartDate)
                     AND DATE < DATEADD(MONTH, -(@I), @EndDate)
    END
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

---

Given the interest in the approach here, I thought I'd try to explain why I went with a loop as opposed to a set based query.

So here is my actual query:

```
DECLARE @EndDate DATE= CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(GETDATE()), '-', MONTH(GETDATE()), '-01') AS DATE)
DECLARE @StartDate DATE= DATEADD(MONTH, -12, @EndDate)


       SELECT count = COUNT(DISTINCT o.ClinicLocationId)
       FROM [order].package p WITH(NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN [order].[order] o WITH(NOLOCK) ON o.packageid = p.packageid
            INNER JOIN Profile.ClinicLocationInfo cli WITH(NOLOCK) ON cli.LocationId = o.ClinicLocationId
                AND cli.FacilityType IN('CLINIC', 'HOSPITAL')
       WHERE CAST(p.ShipDTM AS DATE) >= @StartDate
             AND CAST(p.ShipDTM AS DATE) < @EndDate
             AND p.isshipped = 1
             AND o.IsShipped = 1
             AND ISNULL(o.iscanceled, 0) = 0
```

This gives me a count of 1670, which I know is correct because I have an older report with which to compare output. So when I add a date column to the `SELECT` statement, which is then also added to the `GROUP BY`, I get a list of numbers. You would *think* that by simply tallying the count column within those date ranges, you'd get the same value. But that is not what happens here. For just the first row, where I'd expect a tally of 1670, I'm actually getting 3956. I believe this is because of how Active is being calculated.

Active is determined by a rolling 12 month range. So for example, as of 7/1/2022 (with a starting date of 7/1/2021), there are 1670 locations. If I wanted to look to see how many Active locations there were as of 6/1/2022, I'd have to subtract a month from my @Start and @End to attain that rolling 12 month block. This is why I went with a loop, it seemed much easier to get my results this way. I just verified it takes 7 seconds to run for a 15-month span.

So given this further explanation, I'm curious if there would be a set-based solution for this? I did try the answer provided by Joel, but it did not produce correct numbers (understandable as he did not have more information that's now provided).

Comment: Why use a `WHILE` at all? What are you trying to achieve with looping, which is something SQL is *very bad* at?

Comment: Well, this works pretty well. Takes about 6-10 seconds to capture my count of Active store locations based largely on a date range.

Comment: But why use a `WHILE` loop at all and not a set based solution?

Comment: I see you have a counter for 15 iterations, but go back 12 months in the past. Are you wanting to also look three months into the future?

Comment: This is what came to mind first, and like I said, given that it ran quickly, I didn't see a need to investigate a more efficient approach.

Comment: Joel: Nothing in the future. The 12 months back is part of the query that determines Active status, so the 15 iterations is how far to go with that date range as a qualifier

Comment: I suspect that 6-10 second is incredibly slow compared to something that could likely run in less than a second

Comment: You're probably right. I suppose I'd have to consider how to rewrite as a set based query. I think it was done this way because of the complexity of the dates involved.

Comment: Likely a simple tally, or numbers tables would be much easier here for performance.

Comment: Larnu - I think I know what you mean. I suppose I'll go back and see if I can't refactor my query to a set-based query instead.

Comment: So... you loop between `0` and the count of distinct `value` between a year ago and the start of this month and in that loop you get a count of distinct `value` between the 12 month range offset the number of months that are in the loop counter? What is the relationship between `count(disinct value)` and the offset in months? Every iteration of the loop resets the value in variable `count`... Why loop at all? This is all very confusing and, at the end of the day, Larnu is correct that this should be changed over to set based. I would imagine it would be pretty simple.

Comment: Thanks for your input JNevill. I am currently looking into this change.

Comment: Also get rid of those "NOLOCK" hints. They are not the automatic "go faster" button you may have heard, and can actually cause your query to return stale data.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something - a loop isn't necessary here.  This should be a simple grouping query.  Query the table for the full range and use DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [DATE]), 0) to get the first of the month for [DATE] and group on that value, and use COUNT(DISTINCT value) as the aggregation.

Comment: To expand on my `NOLOCK` comment, the query hint can _sometimes_ (not always!) help a query go a little faster, but the query runs when it is likely to make a difference tend towards _the same query runs where it's at risk for returning bad data._ That is, if it helps you, it's probably because it skipped a lock that was actually important.

Comment: Also - to get the first of this month DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0) as your end date - and you can use DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()) - 12, 0) as your start date.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would hep immensely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is moving the `SET @I = @I + 1` line to **after** the rest of the loop body (and then also run for one iteration longer). In this way, the first adjustment for the dates is still 0. **But don't do this.**

> I'm thinking my issue is based on how I've written the loop

It's not in how you've written the loop, but that a loop was written at all. Nearly every case where you want to use a loop in SQL there is a set-based alternative that is **vastly** more efficient... usually multiple orders of magnitude. This is no exception. Six-ten seconds is an eternity for a process like this; no reason it shouldn't finish almost instantly.

The code for that will look something like this:

```
WITH
    -- generate numbers
    L0   AS(SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1), -- 2^1
    L1   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B), -- 2^2
    L2   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B), -- 2^4
    L3   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B), -- 2^8
    Nums AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1 AS n FROM L3),
    -- project numbers as start and end dates
    Dates As (SELECT TOP 17 
                  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, current_timestamp) -n-12, 0) as StartDate, 
                  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, current_timestamp) -n, 0) as EndDate 
              FROM Nums ORDER BY n)

SELECT d.StartDate, COUNT(DISTINCT value) as [count]
FROM [TABLE] t
-- use the dates to filter the table
INNER JOIN Dates d on t.[Date] > = d.StartDate and t.[Date] < d.EndDate
GROUP BY d.StartDate
```

Or I can show this as actually runnable code:

```
WITH
    L0   AS(SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
    L1   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
    L2   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
    L3   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
    Nums AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1 AS n FROM L3),
    Dates As (SELECT top 17 
                 DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, current_timestamp) -n-12, 0) as StartDate, 
                 DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, current_timestamp) -n, 0) as EndDate 
              FROM Nums ORDER BY n)

SELECT StartDate, EndDate
FROM  Dates d
```

We can see [this gives 17 results with same start and end values as a modified version of the original code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=606f23077e4c458a862f9404a31d5168) in the question.

---

**Update**:

Now that we have the full original code, I can adapt my answer to use it:

```
WITH
    L0   AS(SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1), -- 2^1
    L1   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B), -- 2^2
    L2   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B), -- 2^4
    L3   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B), -- 2^8
    Nums AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1 AS n FROM L3),
    Dates As (SELECT TOP 17 
                  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, current_timestamp) -n-12, 0) as StartDate, 
                  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, current_timestamp) -n, 0) as EndDate 
              FROM Nums ORDER BY n
)
SELECT d.StartDate, COUNT(DISTINCT o.ClinicLocationId) As [count]
FROM [order].package p
INNER JOIN [order].[order] o ON o.packageid = p.packageid
INNER JOIN Profile.ClinicLocationInfo cli ON cli.LocationId = o.ClinicLocationId
    AND cli.FacilityType IN ('CLINIC', 'HOSPITAL')
-- PLEASE tell me ShipDTM is a datetime value and not a varchar
INNER JOIN Dates d ON d.StartDate <= p.ShipDTM and p.ShipDTM < d.EndDate
WHERE p.IsShipped = 1 and o.IsShipped = 1 o.IsCanceled IS NULL
GROUP BY d.StartDate
```

Alternatively, if this still somehow gives you the wrong results (I think the `GROUP BY` will have fixed it), you can use an `APPLY` instead, like so (the `JOIN`/`GROUP BY` should still be faster):

```
WITH
    L0   AS(SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1), -- 2^1
    L1   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B), -- 2^2
    L2   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B), -- 2^4
    L3   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B), -- 2^8
    Nums AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1 AS n FROM L3),
    Dates As (SELECT TOP 17 
                  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, current_timestamp) -n-12, 0) as StartDate, 
                  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, current_timestamp) -n, 0) as EndDate 
              FROM Nums ORDER BY n
)
SELECT d.StartDate, counts.[count]
FROM Dates d
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT count = COUNT(DISTINCT o.ClinicLocationId)
    FROM [order].package p 
    INNER JOIN [order].[order] o ON o.packageid = p.packageid
    INNER JOIN Profile.ClinicLocationInfo cli ON cli.LocationId = o.ClinicLocationId
        AND cli.FacilityType IN('CLINIC', 'HOSPITAL')
    WHERE p.ShipDTM >= d.StartDate
        AND p.ShipDTM < d.EndDate
        AND p.isshipped = 1
        AND o.IsShipped = 1
        AND IsCanceled IS NOT NULL
) counts
```

One final note here, regarding the `ShipDTM` column. I know you may not have any control over this, but the `CAST()` around that column makes it look like it's a `varchar` or similar. If it is, you should see if you can fix it, and I say "fix" because [the schema really is considered **broken**](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2022/07/13/sql-and-dates/).

As it is, you're likely converting *every row in the table* to a Date value — even rows you don't need. Thanks to internationalization issues, these conversion are not the simple or fast process you might expect; in fact converting between either date or numeric and string values is *always* something to avoid as much as possible. They also *invalidate any index you might have on the column*. Even worse, you are **repeating these conversions for each iteration!** No wonder the query runs for multiple seconds!

Almost much as the loop, these conversions are likely the source of the slowness. The good news is the the `JOIN` + `GROUP BY` version of my solution should at least get you back to only needing to convert these values **once**. *Fixing the column* (because again: it is *broken*) will get yet another speed boost. I do understand this is likely to be either above your pay grade or a vendor system you can't change, but you should at least bring up the issue with someone who can influence this: either an architect/senior dev or the vendor directly.

Comment: Thanks Joel. This does in fact work, and runs in about 3-4 seconds. I'm going through it to see if I can understand why this works. I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: Fix that date column, and it will go even faster.

Comment: That date column is indeed a datetime. I use the CAST simply for formatting. I didn't realize it worked that in-depth throughout the query. In the future, I will save such functions for when the result set is notably smaller (for instance, only use it for a handful of rows within a temp table), if I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: It's not about the result set. It has to do this **for every row in the original table**, whether it's in the results or not, because it can't know if the row meets the criteria until after it completes the cast. It also breaks the chance to use any index you might have on the column for this query. But at least the cast is faster than converting from a string.

Comment: Sorry - that's what I meant to say, but wasn't communicated well. So by doing that on a temp table, where the total number of rows are drastically reduced, this would be the best way to use it. And this is specific to a temp table that is going to house the filtered results of another query that are fewer in rows. And noted on the index, that's a good tip I wasn't aware of, thank you.

Comment: I'd tend to avoid the temp table, too, and JOIN this to the other query directly.